# Cleaning up my .bash_profile: Can I delete some of this?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, macports

I'm not a Unix guru.

I'm running OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion. Today I removed Macports from my machine. I believe  macports left some cruft in my `~/.bash_profile which I would like to remove (the cruft—not the entire file contents). Currently, my $PATH looks like this:

`echo $PATH /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

I see some redundancy i.e. `/opt/local/bin:` appears 3 times. In my home directory I see several files relating to `.bash_profile`:

```
ls .bash*
.bash_history
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-08-10_at_10:09:18
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-08-10_at_10:00:21
```

Can I remove the two `.bash_profile.macports…` files?
How can I remove the extra items listed in my $PATH?

Answer (score 2):

The `.bash_profile.macports-saved...` are not actually executed, they're just backups. You can remove them if you don't need them.

`.bash_history` contains the last commands you executed on the shell. There's no point in deleting it, but you can remove it if you want.

If you uninstalled MacPorts (and deleted `/opt`), you can remove from your `PATH` all the subdirectories of `/opt`.

Just look in `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` for any modification of your `PATH`.

For example, in my `.profile` MacPorts added:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

You can remove lines like this, or just single directories.

Comment: Thank you. To remove items from my PATH, is that done by writing a new export command like the one you have shown which exclude the items I want to remove?

Comment: You can reset the PATH, of course, but the best idea is to remove the directories from the commands which added them. You should find those commands in the files listed above, into your home folder. Try editing `.profile` in a text editor, the settings should be there. Also see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard).

Comment: @pietrodn - the edit should be for .bash_profile and .bashrc  not .profile - look at the INVOCATION section of `man bash` to see all the files it uses